# reCAPTCHA in Angular2Dart

Tags: recaptcha, angular-dart, angular2-dart

I am trying to use google reCAPTCHA  in an Angular2dart app.  In index.html  I have

https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'>

component's  mark-up  has -

div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey=" site key val  ">

However  captcha  is not displayed  in Dartium  even after refresh.  If I build the app   using pub build,  deploy it to a container, and then  access it using Chrome or other browsers, captcha  is not displayed  the first time but upon  refresh,   captcha is displayed.  Is there a Dart library  similar to Angular recaptcha  (https://github.com/VividCortex/angular-recaptcha)?

Moreover,  how can  I access reCaptcha response in the controller ?  I tried using

@ViewChild('heroForm') NgForm heroForm;

but  heroForm.value  map does not contain  reCaptcha response.

Comment: Is it possible to post more code about how you try to use recaptcha inside you component ?

Comment: Only code I have in component is  '<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey=" site key val ">'.   If I put this line of code in index.html, captcha is displayed.  but if I put this code in component, it is not displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this
https://github.com/lejard-h/angular_recaptcha

The problem is that the component is load after the recaptcha script, so you have to render the captcha by yourself.

I did a simple component but without the full form integration, feel free to fork and pull request.

Comment: When I tried to use it, I get this error -   Loading angular2 and dart_to_js_script_rewriter transformers...
Serving captcha web on http://localhost:54136
[DirectiveProcessor on captcha|lib/app_component.dart]:
ERROR: Invalid argument (absoluteUri): Value passed must be an absolute uri:

Comment: Can you try with the last version `0.0.3` ? if you still have issue, put it on github, it is better than here.

Comment: Here is a sample demo i did using @HadrienLejard component - https://sureshg.github.io/recaptcha-ng2dart/